# How to configure Https on Tomcat 7 with SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl, https, tomcat7, ssl-certificate

I want to configure https on my Tomcat Server. I got FreeSSL certificate. But I don't know steps to proceed.

> 1. I got an email from FreeSSL provider with the text of the SSL certificate
>   2. I copied this text into file with extension .p7b
>   3. I added this certificate to new keystore
>   4. In server.xml I inserted path to this keystore and the pass as in:

```
<Connector
  SSLEnabled='true'
   keystoreFile="/path/to/certificates/keystore"
    keystorePass="password"
  maxSpareThreads='75'
  port='8443'
  proxyPort='443'
  algorithm='SunX509'
  enableLookups='false'
  secure='true'
  maxThreads='150'
  connectionTimeout='20000'
  disableUploadTimeout='true'
  scheme='https'
  minSpareThreads='5'
  maxHttpHeaderSize='8192'
  sslProtocol='SSL'
  acceptCount='200'
  clientAuth='false'
sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1"
 ciphers="TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
                        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
                        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
                        SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
                        SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"
/>
```

But after this steps I get next error:

> Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption
>   algorithm(s). (Error code: ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap)

on FireFox and

> A secure connection cannot be established because this site uses an
>   unsupported protocol. Error code: ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

on Chrome

**EDIT:**
When I requested SSLCertificate I created cert.csr and keystore.keystore. But now I don't use them. Can this be the problem?

**EDIT2:**

As was written in comments I found the initial keystore and I put in it new certificate. After this I got an error on firefox:

> Secure Connection Failed
>
> The connection to domain.com:8443 was interrupted while the page was loading.
>       The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
>       Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.

Comment: Yes that is exactly the problem. You must "import" the cert chain from the CA into the **same keystore entry as used to generate the CSR**, then use that (or a copy of it). Any SSL server or other PK prover must have *both* the privatekey *and* the cert chain, and the way Java implements this is to combine them in one "privatekey" entry in a keystore.

Comment: I uploaded the key from CA to the store, but after this firefox says:
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at izsearch.com.

    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

Comment: Actually "interrupted while loading" (which I also get on 8443) in your edit is NOT the same thing as "can't connect ... unavailable or busy" (I get on 443) in the comment. For the former, Wireshark shows FIN in response to ClientHello, without even an alert, which suggests a pretty serious server problem. Do you have anything relevant in the server log(s) at the time of that error?

Comment: No, I have no relevant logs for this trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I set one way SSL for Tomcat 7

Hope it would be help

```
$Tomcat\bin>keytool -genkey -v -alias ***your alias*** 
-keyalg RSA -validity ***how many days*** 
-keystore ***your keystore file path*** keystore 
-dname "CN=***www.yourdomain.com***, 
OU=***Your Organizational Unit***, O=***Your Organization***, 
L=***Your City***, ST=***Your State***, C=***Your Country correct***" 
-storepass ***your keystore password*** -keypass ***your key password***
```

---

And in the `server.xml`

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
           keystoreFile="***your keystore file path***"
           keystorePass="***your keystore password***" />
```

Comment: But as I understood you this is the way with self-signed certificate. But I want to put authority signed one.

Comment: For a CA-signed certificate, you have to do exactly what @dave_thompson_085 told you.